# Could not find User without an id - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am just beginning to work with Rails. I have a model, "User" and it has many "List". On the user show view I have created a form to create a list for the current user. When the form is submitted I get the following error:

> Couldn't find User without an ID

I assume that there is something wrong with the way I have setup the nested List form.

User -> show.html.erb

```
    <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <b>Username:</b>
  <%= @user.username %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Password:</b>
  <%= @user.password %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Email:</b>
  <%= @user.email %>
</p>

<h2>Add a List</h2>
 <%= form_for([@user, @user.lists.build]) do |f| %>
 <div class ="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <%=f.label :description%><br />
    <%=f.text_field :description%>
</div>
<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
</div>

<% end %>



<%= link_to 'Edit User', edit_user_path(@user) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back to Users', users_path %>
```

This is the list 'create' controller action.

```
 class ListsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @list = @user.lists.create(params[:list])
        redirect_to user_path(@user)        
    end
end
```

Update: show method on UserController

```
 # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end
```

Update: My routes

```
    resources :users do
      resources :lists
  end

  get "home/index"
```

So is params[:id] nil somehow? What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using `params[:user_id]` in create action, not `params[:id]`

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id]) 
        @list = @user.lists.create(params[:list])
        redirect_to user_path(@user)        
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this? Since this isn't RESTUL routing (see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) you might have to specify the URL (controller and action) you want the form to hit in the form_for tag. If this still isn't passing the user id, you can also use a hidden_field to pass it explicitly in the form. Let me know if this doesn't do the trick...

In the view (show.html.erb)

```
<h2>Add a list</h2>
<%= form_for [@user, @list] do |f| %>
<div class ="field">

<%= f.label :title %><br />
<%= f.text_field :title %>

<%=f.label :description%><br />
<%=f.text_field :description%>

<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

In the Users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @list = @user.list.new
  end
end
```

And in the Lists controller:

```
 class ListsController < ApplicationController
   def create
     @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
     @list = @user.lists.build(params[:list])
     @list.save
     redirect_to @user # or wherever
   end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I get the same error message however. I am basically adapting the blog tutorial on rubyonrail.org site. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-the-blog-application

Comment: I just tried to replicate with a quick app and seems to work for me. What are your routes? The above will work if you have your routes nested, i.e 
resources :users do
resources :lists
end
will take a look at the rails guides sample app too...

Comment: and last comment...make sure you've got user_id as a foreign key in lists if you have them in a belongs_to/has_many relationship...

Comment: I believe i have my routes created correctly. I have updated my post to show this. Thanks!

Comment: @Nick: Are you sure you have `@user = User.find(params[:user_id])` in your create action? (And not `@user = User.find(params[:id])`)

Answer (score 0):

At least in Rails 4 (not sure about previous versions), if you pass a param in the form for something in the new view, if you want to call that param in the create action, you need to slightly modify the call to `resource_name_params[:user_id]` rather than simply `params[:user_id]`.

Specifically in your case, your create method in the controller may need to look like this instead:

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController
   def create
     @user = User.find(list_params[:user_id])
     @list = @user.lists.build(list_params)
     ...
```